# Emf induced by a solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Could someone please clear my confusion regarding this concept and point out what is wrong with my argument:

Say we have a simple circuit as shown in the image:

[image]

Why is the potential difference between points b and a not equal to L*di/dt but is instead -Ldi/dt?

Since the magnetic flux through the solenoid is increasing, the current induced between a and b opposes the direction of the original current. So point b must be at a higher potential than point a and this implies Vb-Va=Ldi/dt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the two currents is incorrect. There is only one current. The way the circuit is drawn the current flows clockwise. Current always enters the positive end of passive elements when they are absorbing or dissipating energy.
The voltage is placed across the RL combination such that $$V_{a}>V_{b}>V_{c}$$ So $V_{ab}$ is positive, then $V_{ba}$ is negative.$$V_{ab}=L\frac {di}{dt}$$$$V_{ba}=-Ldi/dt$$

It is a mistake to think the currents is induced here. The current is caused by the electric field placed by the voltage source. As the current increases the magnetic flus increases. So the magnetic flux is caused by the current, not the other way. An opposing *voltage* is created by the changing flux (Faraday and Lenz):$$V_{ab} =-\frac {d\phi}{dt}=-\frac {d\phi}{di}\frac {di}{dt}$$
Defining $$L=-\frac {d\phi}{di}$$
yields$$V_{ab}=L\frac {di}{dt}$$